# how to randomly select different numbers of prize objects in a lottery system, android / java

Tags: android, random

making an android app to do a lottery prize system.

I want to randomly select winners of prizes.  but each of the prizes are in different amounts. they are currently stored in a database as three columns,  first is index id, auto incremented, the second is the name of the prize, and third is the number of each of these prizes.

for example the most expensive prize is a car and there will be only one of them.  but the next cheaper prize will be a small 50 cc scooter, about 10 of them.  and the list goes down to to a pencil and pen set where there are 800 winners for this prize.

so the chance of winning the pencil and pen set is much higher than the other prizes.

i am trying to get the idea on what is the best way to code this.  i understand that random number generator and even a better one that more evenly distributes true random numbers.

what i am not clear on is the best way to go about this with the different frequency for each of the prizes.

can someone point me in the right direction for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest and least error prone way => put all the prizes in an array. Each prize should be put as many times as there are prizes of the given type. Then generate a random number up to the size of the array and see what is the prize at the given index.

Note that this only considers the case when you know the given user **will win a prize**. Maybe you should first give a way bigger chance for the user **not to win anything** for instance say you have 4000 total prizes and you want a user to win a prize with 1/40 chance. So generate a random number up to `40*4000 = 160000` and if the number is not less than `4000` the user wins nothing, otherwise he wins the prize at the index corresponding to the generated value.

Comment: that is a fantastic answer to my question.  like a lighthouse to a lost ship.   now it makes sense in my head.   you are correct in your guess that there are many that will not win anything. so i have to make a larger total number, so you answered my second question before i even asked it.    now I can get to coding.

Comment: take care that if you have to many prizes your array will be really huge and consume memory.

Answer (score 2):

Compute the sum of "number of each of these prizes".

Pick a random number between 1 and this sum.

Then order the prizes according some criteria and associate a range to each price (the only car will have the range [1;1]).

Ensure the ranges don't overlap each other. The size of each range must be equal to amount of available prices.

Find the range holding your random number and that's it.

Comment: +1 A better solution than mine in memory consumption, worse in computation complexity(you need to find the range in which the prize is located which will be at least O(log(N)) instead of my constant compexity). This solution is harder to implement and a bit more error-prone but saves memory. Depending on the use case might be preferred. This solution is definitely worth mentioning.

Comment: it is difficult to select the best answer between the two.  this is probably better for situation if there are a vary large number of prizes.  however it looks more complex for me to code.  I have only been programming for 5 months.   in my example of 800 for the smallest prize.  i think that is exaggerated.  there probably will not be that many prizes.  it is an estimate

Answer (score 1):

```
Random rand = new Random();
int pickedNumber = rand.nextInt(100);


if(pickednumber>99)

{
    pen or pencil
}

else
{
car
}
```

I'm giving you example and you must me add more condition for scooter or any thing which you want to add on lottery.